# How to show font awesome icon dynamically?

Tags: android

I am working in an Android application in which i get font awesome code in json format, How do i show that icons in my application ,I am getting code like this `"\uf004"` and my approach is like this

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        myHolder.icon.setTypeface(type);

//current.vendor_icon getting code here

     myHolder.icon.setText(current.vendor_icon);
 //When using Iconify
  myHolder.icon.setText("fa-heart-o");
```

and my Textview

```
    <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
        android:text="I {fa-heart-o} to {fa-code} on {fa-android}"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:background="#63000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not averse to libraries you can use `Iconify`. You then create an `IconTextView` and set the text to the appropriate value e.g. `{fa-spotify}`.

You can view the documentation here: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

In code this will look like `textView.setText("{fa-heart-o}")`

Comment: Have you added the correct gradle dependency for fontawesome and also extended the `Application` class (shown under Install)?

Comment: Yes, when I am adding "fa-heart-o" on my XML TextView I am getting icon, but when i am using it inside my code (as shown above) I am not getting icon

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I missed that. Try setting the text to `{fa-heart-o}` rather than `fa-heart-o`.

Comment: Thanks Its Working !!!!!!!!!!!, But how do I achieve same using code (getting code from json)?

Comment: You'll have to convert the JSON to the correct format. If you look here http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/ you can see you want yours to be `&#xf004;` rather than `\uf004`. Personally I would refer to the cheat sheet as I would want to reduce unnecessary network calls but it's your decision :)

Comment: I have used this &#xf004; but its not working, that's why instead of "&#x" I used "\u"